# How to read a 2-D array and write it into console as a matrix

Tags: c#, arrays, matrix, optimization, multidimensional-array

I wanted to read a 2-D array and write it as a matrix to the console.My code is shown below

To read the Array

```
int[][] arr = new int[3][];
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    arr[i] = Array.ConvertAll(Console.ReadLine().Split(' '),aTemp => Convert.ToInt32(aTemp));
}
```

To write the array as matrix to the console

```
for(int i=0;i<arr.GetLength(0);i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<arr.GetLength(1);j++)
    {
         Console.WriteLine("\t" + arr[i][j]);
    }
}
```

However when I enter the input in the console and try to run, I am getting an Index out of bound exception in here

```
arr.GetLength(1);
```

I then tried initializing the column too like this with both row and column 
"int[][] arr = new int[3][3];".

At that time another error comes saying

> Invalid rank specifier:expected ','or ']'

Then I tried initializing the array as below

```
"int[,] arr = new int[3,3];"
```

The invalid rank specifier error gone this time but error comes in the line of reading array elements,

probably this error may be due to not using `arr[i][j]` and reading each elements.

I just want to know what was the mistake in my initial code,that I don't get the value of GetLength(1).
and What is the difference between `int[,] arr = new int[3,3];` and `int[][]arr = new int[3][3];`

and also is there any optimized way to read a 2-d array like the statement, rather than using 2 for loops.

I hope the question is clear. It would be so nice if somebody helps me with this problem. Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: Is it an array of integers, or real numbers?

Comment: And do you know the number of rows in the array from before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int[,]` is a [multidimensional array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays)

`int[][]` is a [jagged array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays), which is an array of arrays. A jagged array as described like this doesn't have a rank, and calling `GetLength(rank)` will cause an error as it only has one technical dimension to the compiler. It's just a single array, with each element filled with another array.

To write a jagged 2d array into a matrix, you could take advantage of [`string.Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netcore-3.1)

> Concatenates the elements of a specified array or the members of a
> collection, using the specified separator between each element or
> member.

```
var arr = new [] {new []{1,2,3},new []{4,5,6},new []{7,8,9}};

for(int i = 0; i< arr.Length; i++)
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ",arr[i] ));
```

**Output**

```
1, 2, 3
4, 5, 6
7, 8, 9
```

Or another approach

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
   for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].Length; j++)
      Console.Write(arr[i][j] + " "); 
   Console.WriteLine();
}
```

or

```
foreach (var t in arr)
{
   foreach (var t1 in t)
      Console.Write(t1 + " ");
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

or

```
var result = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, arr.Select(x => string.Join(", ", x)));
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

For a multi dimensional 2d arrays, you can then call `GetLength(rank)` to get the length of that particular dimension

```
var arr = new [,] {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};

for (var i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(0); i++)
{
   for (var j = 0; j < arr.GetLength(1); j++)
      Console.Write(arr[i, j]);
   Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @TheGeneral that defining jagged arrays have many advantages. I personally like to show 2D array data with fixed-width columns.

For example

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var data = new[] { new[] { 1, 2, 3 }, new[] { 4, 5, 6 }, new[] { 7, 8, 9 } };
    var matrix = new MatrixJagged(data);

    Console.WriteLine("Matrix =");
    Console.WriteLine(matrix.ToTableFormat(4));
    // Matrix =
    // | 1    2    3 |
    // | 4    5    6 |
    // | 7    8    9 |
}
```

Here is starting jagged array class to be able to store data, read data and format it into a table.

```
public class MatrixJagged
{
    readonly int[][] data;

    public MatrixJagged(int[][] data)
    {
        this.data = data;
        this.RowCount = data.Length;
        this.ColumnCount = data.Length > 0 ? data[0].Length : 0;
    }
    public MatrixJagged(int rowCount, int columnCount, int[] array)
    {
        RowCount = rowCount;
        ColumnCount = columnCount;
        this.data = new int[rowCount][];
        int index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
        {
            var row = new int[columnCount];
            Array.Copy(array, index, row, 0, columnCount);
            this.data[i] = row;
            index += columnCount;
        }
    }
    public MatrixJagged(int rowCount, int columnCount)
    {
        RowCount = rowCount;
        ColumnCount = columnCount;
        this.data = new int[rowCount][];
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            data[i] = new int[columnCount];
        }
    }
    public ref int this[int row, int column] { get => ref data[row][column]; }
    public int[] GetRow(int row) => data[row];
    public int RowCount { get; }
    public int ColumnCount { get; }

    public static MatrixJagged ReadFrom(string path)
    {
        return ReadFrom(File.OpenText(path));
    }
    public static MatrixJagged ReadFrom(StreamReader reader)
    {
        var rows = new List<int[]>();
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = reader.ReadLine();
            var parts = line.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            var row = parts.Select((s) => int.Parse(s)).ToArray();
            rows.Add(row);
        }
        return new MatrixJagged(rows.ToArray());
    }

    public string ToTableFormat(int columnWidth, bool withBrackets=true)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < RowCount; i++)
        {
            if (withBrackets) { sb.Append("| "); }
            sb.Append(string.Join(" ", data[i].Select(
                (x) => x.ToString().PadLeft(columnWidth))));
            if (withBrackets) { sb.Append(" |"); }
            sb.AppendLine();
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```